# Booting Fedora 30 32bit live iso VirtualBox: Error "This kernel requires an x86-64 CPU, but only detected an i686 CPU."

Tags: linux, fedora, virtualbox, virtual-machine

Having an issue trying to install Fedora 30 32bit in my 32bit VM. When I try to start my vm in virtualbox using Fedora-Workstation-Live-x86_64-30-1.2.iso, it shows the error:

This kernel requires an x86-64 CPU, but only detected an i686 CPU. Unable to boot - please use a kernel appropriate for your CPU.

Vm setting for Fedora 30:

Type: Linux

Version: Fedora 32bit

Host OS: Windows 10 Pro x64

Anyone know the reason why this happens and a workaround/fix for this?

Hyper V is off already and Virtualization settings in bios are On. I have successfully installed both Ubuntu 16 32bit and Ubuntu 20 64bit, but can't install fedora 30 using 32bit with 32bit settings.

Thank you.

Comment: *Fedora-Workstation-Live-**x86_64**-30-1.2.iso* means a 64-bit ISO, not 32-bit. Why would you even use 32-bit Linux nowadays?

Answer (score 1):

INFO: The architecture x86_64 refers to a 64bit platform. On the VM type, you must select the appropriate bit width (32 or 64 bit) for the system you would like to install in order to work. You can install a 32bit system on a 64bit CPU, but not the reverse (which is what you're trying to do).

PROBLEM: Your VM is configured to emulate a 32bit CPU and you're trying to install a 64bit OS.

SOLUTION: You must use an ISO which says i686 (related to 32bit), not the x86_64 (related to 64bit).

Unfortunately, many recent Linux distributions do not release a 32bit version of their system anymore, you're probably stuck with old versions if you're interested in using the i686 architectures.